# How to use Android KeyStore API with API 18?

Tags: java, android, security

How do I get the equivalent code below when I'm targeting API 18? Code below works only for API 23 and above. Also how secure would the API 18 code be, given that we can't use `KeyGenParameterSpec` and the API 18 code might use deprecated APIs?

```
KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(
    KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, "AndroidKeyStore");

keyGenerator.init(new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(alias,
    KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
    .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
    .setKeySize(256)
    .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
    .setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(400)
    .setRandomizedEncryptionRequired(false)
    .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)
    .build());

SecretKey key = keyGenerator.generateKey();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
private final String ENCRYPTION_ALIAS = "anEncryptionAlias"

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, AndroidKeyStore);
    generator.initialize(new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
        ENCRYPTION_ALIAS,
        KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_VERIFY)
        .setDigests(
            KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256,
            KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA512)
        .build()
    );
    generator.generateKeyPair();
} else {
    Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
    end.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
    KeyPairGeneratorSpec spec = new KeyPairGeneratorSpec
        .Builder(YourApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext())
        .setAlias(ENCRYPTION_ALIAS)
        .setSubject(new X500Principal("CN=Your Company ," +
            " O=Your Organization" +
            " C=Your Coountry"))
        .setSerialNumber(BigInteger.ONE)
        .setStartDate(start.getTime())
        .setEndDate(end.getTime())
        .build();
    KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, AndroidKeyStore);

    generator.initialize(spec);
    generator.generateKeyPair();
}
```

Comment: please replace your projects constants with their values

Comment: @AliBehzadianNejad I'm sorry about that. I've updated the code.

Comment: **KeyPairGeneratorSpec** is not the same thing as **KeyGenerator**

Comment: `KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA` Field still requires API level 23